# powershell oracle insert data from text file

Tags: oracle, powershell, oracle11g

I am looking to insert data from a tab delimited text file into an Oracle 11g database using a PowerShell script.  I realize there may be better tools or methods to do this but I have been given a task and my tools are limited.  My previous script used a SQLLDR command to load the data but I need to rewrite the script without SQLLDR

So far I have been looking into using some of the ODP .NET functionality as well as OleDBConnections but I seem to run into roadblocks each time.

My hope is to use the OracleDataAcess and OracleDataTable methods in ODP .NET to be able to load data into a table from my tab delimited file.  Unfortunately I am fairly new to Oracle and .NET so I'm not sure how best to get the data loaded.

Here is some of the function that get's me access to Oracle.  The query is just a simple select statement on a table in the database.

```
            Add-Type -Path “C:\app\g_dawdy\product\11.2.0\client_2\odp.net\bin\2.x\Oracle.DataAccess.dll"
            Add-type -AssemblyName System.Data.OracleClient
            $con = New-Object Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection("User Id=$DBUsername;Password=$DBPassword;Data Source=$DBName")     
            $con.Open()
            $cmd = New-Object Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCommand
            $cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM VOIP_VALIDATE "
            $da = New-Object Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDataAdapter($cmd);

            $resultSet = New-Object System.Data.DataTable
            [Void]$da.fill($resultSet)

            $resultSet | Format-Table -AutoSize
            $con.Close()
```

Comment: No idea how to solve this, but it would be interesting to hear why someone thinks that replacing an industry standard data loading tool with a less suitable, more complex, slower performing alternative is a good idea. I suspect it's a case of "architecture astronaut-ology".

Comment: Are you allowed to use external tables (i.e. nothing outside the database)? That would enable you to still do it the easy way rather than the strange one.

Comment: @DavidAldridge I'm probably the low man on the totem pole so I'm not really giving a good picture of the architecture/environment.  One thing I can tell you is that we are slowly moving off Oracle and onto MS SQL.  This Oracle database is one of the remaining critical databases that still needs attention.

Comment: @Ben I believe the external databases can be used but can you elaborate some more on how this would look?

Comment: Not external databases, [external _tables_](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40540/tablecls.htm#CNCPT1141)...